# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Ты права(,) как никогда"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Ты права(,) как никогда"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка.***

Как никогда
Экспрес. 1. Как ни в какое другое время, ни при каких иных условиях. — А ты бдительность не теряй, сейчас она тебе как никогда нужна (Н. Поликарпов. Охота на Лебяжьем). 2. В высшей степени. Она ушла, оставив его… Обломов глядел ей вслед и улыбался. Он был счастлив как никогда (Гончаров. Обломов). Я был настроен радостно, чувствовал себя сильным, как никогда (М. Горький. Мои университеты).

***Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010:***

как никогда

Слова «как никогда» выделяются знаками препинания, обычно запятыми, вместе с относящимися к ним словами.
И тогда-то // Загрохали ставни, // И город, // Артачась, // Оголенный, // Без качеств, // И каменный, как никогда, // Стал собой без стыда. Б. Пастернак, Мужики и фабричные. Я утром гуляла в саду, в поле, была в лесу, мне казалось, что я одна во всем мире, и я думала, так хорошо, как никогда в жизни. И. Бунин, Легкое дыхание. Все было против людей Заозерья в то беспощадное утро: сушь и жара многих недель, состояние залежи и направление ветра, влажность воздуха и низкий, как никогда прежде, уровень грунтовых вод. Е. Парнов, Третий глаз Шивы.
***Если слова «как никогда» тесно связаны по смыслу со сказуемым, то запятые, как правило, не ставятся.***
Солнце пекло как никогда, но у пруда стояло затишье. Г. Белых, А. Пантелеев, Республика ШКИД. И как никогда было обидно, что его опыты – фактически девять лет его жизни – пошли насмарку. В. Богомолов, Момент истины. Он служил как никогда. И. Бунин, Суходол.

***В Вашем примере запятую ставить не следует, так как слова "как никогда" тесно связаны со сказуемым "права".***

Comment: Спасибо.Прекрасный ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция со словом КАК в составе оборотов *как правило, как исключение, как обычно, как всегда, как прежде, как сейчас, как теперь, как один, как народно* и т.п. выделяются запятыми. Но если оборот тесно связан с предикатом и приобретает смысл фразеологизма, запятые не нужны. Поэтому в вашем примере пишем: "Ты права как никогда".

Comment: Но выражение "как никогда" тесно связано со сказуемым.Это как-то влияет?